# Name of the sidebar/taskpane of an office 365 add-in

Tags: office365, office-js, office365api, scriptlab

I have an office 365 addin, whose taskpane/sidebar takes the same name as the addin. How can I change it?
ScriptLab does it. when we click on **Code** on scritlab ribbon, the taskpane has the name as **Code** and when we click on **Run**, another taskpane is opened and it has the name as **Run**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The add-on title comes from the manifest [DisplayName element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/displayname) and cannot be changed dynamically. I didn't put this as the answer because have no idea what ScriptLab's guys have access to and how they've done it. Maybe you'll get lucky and somebody from Microsoft can provide you with the answer.

Comment: That is my understanding as well. But since scriptlab has done it, just wondering if there is actually a way to do it. Anyways, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script Lab is an open source project that has no special access to anything in Office. I would start by inspecting it's manifest: [script-lab-react-prod.xml](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/manifests/script-lab-react-prod.xml).

The `<Action>` element of type ShowTaskpane can have a `<Title>` element that sets a title. See [Action / Title](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/action#title).

Comment: Thanks. This did it. Do you know if this Action/Title was introduced recently or was it always there?

Comment: I believe it has been there since we introduced Add-in Commands, which I think was 2016.